# Is it possible to restore a TFS collection (db backup only) when no detach was performed?

Tags: tfs

Trying to attach the database (DefaultCollection), I get prompted with TF254078: No attachable databases were found on the following instance of SQL Server.

The database is restored and running, but I've copied it from another server running TFS.

It seems that to attach a collection, you would have to do a 'detach' before creating a db backup.

Is it possible to attach a collection to TFS with my current db?

The TFS version is 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can attach an un-detached collection (although someone may correct me on that).  There used to be a tfsconfig.exe recover in 2010 but it wasn't a happy experience and they got rid of it in 2012.

Assuming you have a full backup of the old server (let's call it Server A) and also assuming there are other collections on the new server (let's call that one server B) that you need to retain then you'll have to restore server A, detach the collection and the attach it to the server B.

Comment: I am getting to the same conclusion. Thnx